# Accessing HTTPRequest Headers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, postman

I'm new to developing APIs, and come across some trouble.
I'm sending a request from Postman, with an empty body, and some headers:

[image]

And I'm trying to retrieve these values in my controller.

[image]

This doesn't work though. The request is empty, all the headers are null.
An exception is thrown stating that the requested header cannot be found.
I've searched around, and can't find any reason why this isn't working. I'm guessing it's something to do with the initial request from Postman, but unsure what it is.

Some more pictures of the errors, and content:

[image]
[image]

Can anyone help me out, or direct me to somewhere that might be the correct answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In postman header tab as per you snap `Authorization` field's checkbox is not checked. So it won't pass these header in request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it again in work on a new project, and sent a request from Postman with the Authorization ticked and it worked. On my personal project above, when I tick the authorization checkbox, it says something along the lines of 'This will be overridden by Postman'. I'll try again at home, and update this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference:

I found my issue was something to do with my app being .NET Core. As it was a new app, I switched it over to .NET Framework. As soon as I did this, I began retrieving the correct HttpRequestMessage with headers included.